# Get the actual position of element after pagination in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, pdf, phantomjs, wkhtmltopdf

[Ubuntu 14.01, wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1]

wkhtmltopdf would change the position of the row element to avoid the page break. So I can't obtain the accurate position of each element.

The original HTML, to-be-rendered.html

```
....
<p class="SECTION">3. GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</p>
<p class="a">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</p>
<p class="c">AAAAAAAAA</p>
<p class="d">BBBBBBBBBBBBB</p>
<p class="c">CCCCCCCCCCC</p>
<p class="d">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</p>
<p class="c">EEEEEEEEEE</p>
....
```

To debug, the Y-offset is appended to each element, and there is a 'absoluted' line is posited at 957.

```
//javascript(JQuery)
$("p").each(function(){
  var pi = this;
  pi.html(pi.html()+""+pi.offset()['top']);
})

var hr=document.createElement('hr');
$(hr).addClass("segment").css('top', 957).appendTo("#editor");
```

The html and the rendered pdf without pagination (with a extremely long page-height) are like https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lrEs.png

```
$ wkhtmltopdf -page-height 10000mm to-be-rendered.html output.pdf
```

As it shown, the line(top:957) and the content("BBBBBBBB938" top:938) are well posited where they should be.

**However, the position changed when we chose the limited page-height**

```
$ wkhtmltopdf -page-size A4 to-be-rendered.html output.pdf
```

The "BBBBBBBB938" has been push down as there is no enough space for it in the last page. The top of "BBBBBBBB938" should be approximately at 953px rather than its original 938. As shown in
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRn1u.png

So the question is, is it possible to get the rendered position of the element? I would like to calculate what first line will be in each rendered page, (Because I want to change the header based on the type of first line in each rendered, paginated page), however the rows move after pagination only when rendered. I can't predict it in JS of "to-be-rendered.html".

Any idea?　Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add code? This is pretty abstract at the moment, anything could have gone wrong within your implementation and we wouldn't be able to see it.

Comment: Running heads is what you desire and are easy in solutions based on xsl fo.

Comment: @Unihedron I just change the description. I hope it make sense.

Comment: @KevinBrown Exactly! I would like to render a long HTML to PDF(with pagination), and it seems not relate to xsl fo?

Comment: @KevinBrown Or should I transform HTML to xsl fo first, and then transform XSL-FO to pdf? Is it the procedure?

Comment: on this site http://www.xportability.com/XEPOnline/FOTestSuite.html we use JS to get the structure, content and style and XSL FO to format remote and deliver PDF. You can easily extend the XSL to add what you desire. If you create a fiddle with you sample HTML I will help you augment it.

Comment: Note you can use external css with this if you desire for easier management of content. You would merely edit the XSL to inject the markers in the body and for creating your desired headers and footers.

Comment: The development team is moving servers this morning, you can fork this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kstubs/jrtM5/ if you like. It will be about an hour until they finish.

Comment: @KevinBrown It seems like a cloud-based solution. Is it free and safe to use?   Also, I would prefer to generate the PDF locally to keep it private and safe. Is there any idea?

Comment: It is cloud, it is safe, it is free. If you prefer to format locally you would examine the JS, figure out how to grab the resolved html with external css, download the XSL referred to in the JS that converts to XSL FO, download FOP. Install FOP. Run that FO through FOP. The XSL has only been tested with RenderX so no guarantees.